# Writing C function to return a character and assigning a value to a char variable, but I am having some problem

Tags: c

I am new to C and I am having a bit of trouble. I am wondering why C keeps telling me that I should put '(' in front of '=' while assigning the function's return value to my variable. It also keeps on saying it expected expression before 'char'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char returnText(const char* text) {
  return *text;
}

int main()
{
  const char = returnText("Hello World");
  printf("%s", char);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` is a keyword, you cannot use it as the name of a variable

Comment: Also, `%s` is for strings. Use `%c` for single characters.

Comment: (fix the keyword violation first and then) What would your function do wrong if it did: `const char* returnText(const char* text) { return text; }` instead?

Comment: Understand that all you are doing is passing the address for the string-literal `"Hello World"` to `returnText()` and then simply returning the first character by dereferencing the pointer `text` in `return *text;` To output the character, there is no need to use `printf()`, simply using `putchar(mychar);` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const char = returnText("Hello World");` const char is a keyword, you forgot name it.
%s in printf is for strings/char*. %c is for char only.

```
const char returnText(const char* text) {
  return *text;
}

int main()
{
  const char t = returnText("Hello World");
  printf("%c", t);
  return 0;
}
```

this code is I think you want. function get "Hello World" or const char* and returns a first char.
in the main t is a const char an get the return of function
and printf prints a char. if you want print the full "hello world" string use %s

Comment: From the title it seems that the OP is trying to "return a character" not the whole string.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I try edit little as posible the original code to highlight main errors. but yes remove const is not a lot recomended, it depends on the situation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not sure what you mean. The function return type is `char` in the OP code and that is correct as is AFAICS.

Comment: @kaylum The function in this answer returns a non-`const` pointer to the possibly `const` data.

Comment: @kaylum right, it slipped my mind as I was reading below, I'll fix it now.

Comment: Ok, then your comment should be directed to @RIR and not me. I'm suggesting the answer does not address the question as it changes what the OP actually wants to achieve.

Comment: @kaylum Oh, my bad! Sorry! Deleted that comment. I mistook you for OP. Now it's edited to not violate `const`ness anymore.

Comment: Nit, either `printf ("%c\n", t);` or add a `putchar('\n');` to not mess up my prompt due to your programing not being POSIX compliant and outputting a final `'\n'` with the last output.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The answering person may not get "Nit" in this context.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - you are right, "Nit" may be unclear, what I meant was "Deminimus" `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax for declaring a variable is `data_type identifier`, which can optionally be followed by a definition. You wrote the data type (`char`), but no variable name/identifier. Your compiler is throwing an error because it encounters a variable definition `= returnText("Hello World")` before it encounters a variable identifier. Additionally, since char is a core language keyword, you can't use it as an identifier.

Some other notes you might want to consider:

- Your function `returnText` is of return type char, meaning it will only return the single character pointed to by `text`: In this case it is the `'H'` in `"Hello World"`.
- A pointer to a char `char *` can be used to point to the first character in a string, then passed to printf with the %s flag. Consider changing your variable on line 9 to type "pointer to char" `char *`

You could alternatively use an array of chars `char varname[array_size]` or `malloc` to allocate space in memory, then assign your "Hello World" string to it.

Example using an array of chars:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_TEXT_LEN 12

int main()
{
   char text[MAX_TEXT_LEN] = "Hello World";
   printf("%s", text);
   return 0;
}
```

Example using malloc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define  MAX_TEXT_LEN 12

int main()
{
   char* text = (char*)malloc(MAX_TEXT_LEN);
   text = "Hello World";
   printf("%s", text);
   free(text);
   return 0;
}
```

Note that in both of these examples, `text` represents a pointer to the first character in a string.

Comment: When supplying an example of using `malloc`, please include the same amount of `free`. The `(char*)` on the return from `malloc` isn't needed in C either.